# CodeBuild succeeds while Node build command has failed

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, aws-codebuild

Let's assume that we have AWS CodeBuild project which `buildspec` file contains the following:

```
"phases": {
"install": {
  "runtime-versions": {
    "nodejs": 14
  }
},
"build": {
  "commands": [
    "echo Build started on `date`",
    "npm ci && npm audit --audit-level=critical",
    "node -r esm index.js --env=CLOUDTEST"
  ]
},
"post_build": {
  "commands": [
    "echo Build completed on `date`"
  ]
}
```

It runs successfully, but if, for example, `env` value is wrong, node command will fail, but the build still succeeds.

*Question: what should I do to make CodeBuild project to fail when node command fails?*

Answer (score 1):

The `build` phase transitions to `post_build` [by default](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/view-build-details.html#view-build-details-phases), regardless whether the build succeeds or fails.  To override this behaviour, explicitly set the phase's [on-failure](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/build-spec-ref.html#build-spec.phases) behaviour:

```json
"build": {
  "on-failure": "ABORT",
  "commands": ["node BOOM"]
},
```

The bad `node BOOM` command causes the execution to fail immediately. Logs tail:

```sh
[Container] 2022/04/29 11:21:10 Command did not exit successfully node BOOM exit status 1
[Container] 2022/04/29 11:21:10 Phase complete: BUILD State: FAILED_WITH_ABORT
[Container] 2022/04/29 11:21:10 Phase context status code: COMMAND_EXECUTION_ERROR Message: Error while executing command: node BOOM. Reason: exit status 1
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't help.

Comment: @Rufi `on-failure: ABORT` is a _necessary_ condition.  Why is it not _sufficient_ in your case?  Perhaps your `index.js` is catching, not throwing the error?